# Showing number of elements during paginations

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a way to show the number of elements for each page, for example:

> Page1: 1-5 elements of 327

> Page2: 6-10 elements of 327

> ....

Now I have the opportunity to go to the nextPage, previousPage, lastPage, firstPage, and also the possibility to choose the number of element for every page(for example 5, 10, 20) (this.elementsForPage)

I have tried to create in this way:

```
if(action === "next"){
          this.firstElement += parameters.length
          this.lastElement  += parameters.length
        }
        if(action === "previous"){
          this.firstElement -= parameters.length
          this.lastElement  -= parameters.length
        }
        if(action === "last"){
          this.firstElement = this.totalElements - this.parameters.length
          this.lastElement = this.totalElements
        }
        if(action === "first"){
          this.firstElement = 1;
          this.lastElement = parameters.length 
        }
```

this works if I make next, previous and first. But it doesn't work If I go on the last page.

This is why If I go to the last page and it has only 2 results, for example, i'll have

> firstElement = 327 - 2 = 325

> lastElement = 327

But if I go on "previous" it counts:

> firstElement = 325 - 5 = 320

> lastElement = 327 - 5 = 322

and it is wrong because are showing 5 results not 2.

In your opinion how can I fix these problems?

Comment: floor(327/5)*5 will give you lower bound (always divisble by five) and 327 is your upper limit (could be calculated by floor(327/5) * 5 + (327 mod 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Function

```js
function getCurrentPageItems(currentPage,perPage,total)
{
    currentPage = currentPage - 1;
    let elStart = currentPage*perPage +1;
    let elEnd = elStart+perPage - 1;
    elEnd = Math.min(Math.max(elEnd, 1), total);
    console.log(`Page ${(currentPage+1)}: ${elStart}-${elEnd} of ${total}`);
    return [elEnd,elEnd];
}
getCurrentPageItems(1,5,327);
getCurrentPageItems(2,5,327);
getCurrentPageItems(65,5,327);
getCurrentPageItems(66,5,327);
console.log(327/5);
```

Comment: thank you for answer, I have tried but seems to be a problem anyway, If I go to the last page and then click on previous page

Comment: I don't see the problem `Page 65: 321-325 of 327`, I edited the code above, press `Run code Snippet`. Implement the code as I did there and it will work. When someone presses "next" Just increment page variable then run that function